# Spring cloud stream Kafka Failed to create producer binding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a spring-boot project that has dependencies of `spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` and `spring-cloud-stream` of version 2.1.2. It acts as a producer. When it start, it keeps warning me:

> 2019-05-06 15:00:25.136  WARN 28116 --- [| adminclient-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

and throw an error:

```
2019-05-06 15:01:10.280 ERROR 28116 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: Provisioning exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:290) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:137) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:78) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:193) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:97) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:151) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:290) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:274) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:323) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:299) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:281) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

This is my bootstrap class:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableBinding(Channels.class)
public class Service1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Service1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the `Channels` class :

```
public interface Channels {
    String outputChannel = "myOutputChannel";

    @Output(outputChannel)
    MessageChannel myOutputChannel();
}
```

This is application.properties:

```
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.application.name=service1
server.port=8081

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myOutputChannel.destination=myTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myOutputChannel.content-type=application/json
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are not running Kafka on the local machine. If you want to specify another Kafka Brokers property you can do it in the `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=host1,host2
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.defaultBrokerPort=port
```

The default values for the above two properties are localhost and 9092 and if you are not running a Kafka Cluster on `localhost:9092` your application will fail with that error.